# The variable name '@product_Id' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

i insert the data from datagridview to database table. but the error that come in the exception i write in the title. the value save in the database table as well.

```
private void btnSavePurchases_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPGrandTotal.Text)) || (txtPGrandTotal.Text == "0")) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No record available");
    }
    else
    { 
        try
        {           
            string query1 = "INSERT INTO purchases (productId) values (@product_Id)";
            command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(query1, connection);
            for (int i = 0; i < dGvPurchases.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //   command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("product_Id", dGvPurchases.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will just leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You **keep adding** the `product_id` parameter for each iteration of your `for` loop. Don't do this! **Define** the parameter **once**, outside the loop, and inside the loop **only SET** the value .....

Answer (score 3):

Probably

```
AddWithValue("product_Id"...
```

should be

```
AddWithValue("@product_Id"...
```

By the way, since you add your parameters in a for loop, you need clear them top of your for loop. That's why you need to uncomment your `command.Parameters.Clear()` part. Without `Clear` method, you try to add same parameter name over and over again to same command and you will get an error in your second iteration.

As an another solution, you can declare your parameter name outside of your loop and add it's value inside of loop.

And don't use `AddWithValue` as much as possible. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads to specify your db type and it's size.

Don't forget to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) as well to dispose your command object.

Comment: Both AddWithValue("product_Id" and AddWithValue("@product_Id" will work. The problem is with the for loop, as you also point out.

Comment: @ShellShock Indeed, but as a best practice, it would be better to match exactly and would be better to use `@` to _specify_ them as a parameter IMO..

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `command` anywhere in the scope here. Probably it is a class variable. That is one part of your issue.

Move the construction of the `command` variable to inside your method:

```
var command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(...);
^^^
```

Second, your for look causes issues. You can't add the same parameter over and over again. If you want to `insert` multiple rows, add multiple `insert` statements. Create the `command` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

problem is that `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` adds the parameter to the list of parameters. you can't add a parameter twice. since you call the command several times, define the parameter outside and set value within the loop:

```
string query1 = "INSERT INTO purchases (productId) values (@product_Id)";
command = DBConnectivity.getCommandForQuery(query1, connection);

// Define the Parameter just once
var param = command.Parameters.Add("@product_Id", SqlDbType.Int);

for (int i = 0; i < dGvPurchases.Rows.Count; i++)
{  // set value while looping
   param.Value = dGvPurchases.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: The parameterized query '(@product_Id int)INSERT INTO purchases (productId) values (@prod' expects the parameter '@product_Id', which was not supplied.